Excludung edited file in git commit and staging
Sometimes I need to exclude a edited file. I mean, you need to have it in the repository but for instance you have some local development value which you do not want to commit and push.
Most of the time file is committed accidentally. And creates extra burden like resetting last commit etc.
So, I need a feature like staging but opposite of it. Excludes file from the commit list. Or just exclude the a specific change in some code line.
Is there any feature like this?
Thanks in advance.

Ideally, if you don't want a file or hunk of a file added to the index, don't add it. git add, which stages a file, does not happen automatically; by default, the index at every moment contains, in preparation for the next commit, only what you have explicitly added to it from the working tree.
But let's say you do add a file or hunk of a file to the index and now you have regrets. Well, the opposite of git add, which stages a file, is git restore --staged, which puts the index version of a file into the same state as what's already in the most recent commit — and thus effectively unstages it.
And, like git add, which has a patch mode that lets you select specific hunks to stage, git restore has a patch mode that lets you select specific hunks to unstage.
But, to end with my beginning, I repeat: the best way to handle this is to be more deliberate with your use of git add in the first place. You say "Most of the time file is committed accidentally"; well, don't do that.

Related, if you are editing something like a configuration file, don't edit it directly. Keep something like config.template in the repository, but make a copy named config for actual local use.


I need a feature like staging but opposite of it. Excludes file from the commit list. Or just exclude the a specific change in some code line.

There is no feature that tracks a file but at the same time excludes it from getting staged. In Git, files can only be tracked, ignored or untracked.
Staging is an operation that should be performed sensibly, where only what partakes to a commit should be recorded, and without adding indiscriminately every change to the index. However, mistakes do occur, and, as you said, sometimes happen to inadvertently stage the wrong file(s).
So, if you find yourself to often unstage a certain set of tracked files, you could set up a config file listing their paths. Then, before recording a commit, you could either run git restore --staged --pathspec-from-file=<config_file> or git reset --pathspec-from-file=<config_file> to automatically unstage every undesired file in the configuration.
However, this solution only works if you need to unstage whole files. Instead, if you need to partially unstage the undesired files (or partially stage them, if you look at it from a different point of view), you could use git add --patch, or git add --interactive with the patch option. There is in fact no way to automatically unstage specific chunks of changes from a file. This scenario requires you to be more careful when staging your changes.

If you have a tracked file that you wish git to ignore any changes to, use:
git update-index --skip-worktree FILE

Git will now ignore the file, as though no changes were made.
if you git add DIRECTORY that includes the file, the file will NOT be added.
